# Forgot my personal Developer Account password and security question

Tags: user, developer-org, forgot-your-password

I forgot my personal Developer Account password and security question. But it is still tied to my email Id and I'm getting links when I click on reset password but Then I forgot the answer for my security question. Any ways to get the access back?

Comment: Historically, Salesforce has been really bad about actually resetting a developer account unless it's tied to an ISV, so good luck. If you have a paid subscription org, try submitting your case from that org instead (make sure you have the correct username handy and access to the email on file).

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a Developer Account I assume there is no System Administrator who could reset your password.

Your only solution is to create a case with Customer Support and make sure to include your username.

[See this Knowledge Article for more info.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005251&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: To create that case, it is asking me to login! :-|

Comment: Yes, you can use any org but see sfdcfox's comment above!